# Is it possible to catch a JS event for a user who navigates inside of iframe (same domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page that has a number of iframes that load different pages on the same domain. Each iframe has normal pages which have links, forms, etc.. What I need to do is add a piece of JS to the parent page which would catch event for user navigating inside of any iframe. So if someone clicks something inside of one of iframes or submits a form or does anything like that, I want to catch that. I've tried different variations of this with no luck so far

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("iframe").each(function(){ 
            $(this).bind("unload", function(){
                alert(1);
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage ?

Comment: do you have the control over those pages you open in iframe ?

Comment: yes, I have control and it does work if I assign the event from inside the actual page. but I was wondering if anything can be done for assigning the events from outside those pages.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney is correct the best practice on this is to implement a solution using postMessage() if your browsers supports it (IE7+).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function(){ 
        $(this).contains().find('body').on("click", "a", function(){
            alert('1');
        });
    }); 
});
```

in this way from the parent page you attach an event handler that detects a click on every link inside the iframe and alerts 1. This should work only if the iframe is on the same domain of the main page, otherwise contains() does nothing.

Comment: Why is "addEventListener" not part of the solution?  Could it be, or should it be?

Comment: @BrentArias i use jQuery `on()` function wich add an event listener to the body element. the listener listens to `click` events on `<a>` tags

Comment: This solution may work in the short term, but is not scalable in the sense that it won't support other domains, partners as your app's needs change.